# How do you iterate through a String which is an attribute from an object in Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I have a class Employees.java

```
public class EmployeesForm{
    private String name;
         ....
     public String[] getAllTypes() {
            String[] allTypes = new String[3];
            allTypes[0] = "Manager";
            allTypes[1] = "Dev";
            allTypes[2] = "FA";

        return allTypes; 
     }
}
```

In Struts1 this is how I iterate in allTypes array.

```
<logic:iterate id="type" name="employeesForm" property="allTypes">';
    <option value="<bean:write name=type>" id="typeid_<bean:write name='type'/>">
     <bean:write name="type"/>              
   </option>                        
</logic:iterate>
```

What is the equivalent in Struts2? I tried that but it didn't work :(

```
<s:iterator id="type" name="employeesForm" property="allTypes">
    <option value="<s:property value='type'/>" id="typeid_<s:property value='type'/>">
        <s:property value="type"/>
    </option>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Look at the <select> + <s:iterator> and <s:select> examples in the answer from me. Consider upvoting if helpful

Comment: I doubt that it's a duplicate, not that question though :\